# 'Variable "assetSourceOptions" does not exist' after updating to Craft 2.6

Tags: error-message

When I try to add another field, suddenly I get this error:
"Variable "assetSourceOptions" does not exist"[image]

This started after I updated to Craft 2.6

Comment: +1 got the same thing, but also with editing an existing field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the **Redactor I** plugin was incompatible with Craft 2.6... Fortunately, Brandon fixed this last night!

[Update your version of Redactor I](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI), and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: And now it is officially fixed with a fancy new 1.1.0 version number — and feature parity with Rich Text fields in 2.6!

Comment: I updated and im still getting that same error?  even if i uninstall redactor I plugin?

Comment: @KeithMancuso Did you update it through downloading the ZIP from GitHub? And do you have the latest version of Craft CMS installed?

Comment: @KeithMancuso The error could also be produced by a different plugin. Have you looked into that?